# What about the boundaries of 2 conformally equivalent domains

Tags: complex-analysis

This question was from my Complex analysis assignment and I was unable to attempt it. So, posting it here.

> If 2 domains are conformally equivalent , what can be said about their boundaries?

Let U and V be conformally equivalent , then there exists map p, q such that p:U$\to V$ and q:$V\to U$, such that both p and q are holomorphic and injective.

But I am not sure on how to proceed with the given information and require some hint. Please give a hint?

Comment: the answer is nothing really as for example by RMT all simply connected domains (except the full plane) are conformally equivalent to the unit disc and there are lots of weird such (check out half moon - inside of two interior tangent circles for a simple example, the comb - disc from which inifnitely many segments are removed - for a slighlty more complicated one etc)

Comment: My guess is the intended answer was that the boundary of $U$ is empty if and only if  the boundary of $V$ is empty.